# Como realizar un login correcto con php

Tags: php

Quisiera algo de orientación. Estoy tratando de realizar un *login* con **PHP**. He visto bastantes métodos pero en todos los casos, tanto el usuario como la clave es visible por medio del navegador. En todos los casos he buscado como hacerlo con el método **post** ya que al parecer es el más seguro, pero no sé como ocultar y que los datos enviados por post no sean visibles a través del navegador.

Si me pudieran orientar sería de gran ayuda.

Comment: Los datos enviados por post solo son visibles a traves del navegador del que los envia mirando en la consola (bueno, si me apuras tambien a traves de los servidores intermedios entre el navegante y el servidor del dominio, pero eso ya es rizar el rizo). Son seguros y son los más usados para este tipo de páginas de inicio de sesión. Otro tema seria enviar la contraseña cifrada entre esos datos, o ambas cosas, y que el script que la recoja la sepa interpretar, pero eso no tiene que ver con el método para ser enviado.

Comment: De acuerdo a lo que encontraste deberías plantear algún código y sobre eso ver tus dudas. Así planteada tu pregunta es muy genérica.